# rails 4 complex SQL scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Users` which `has_many EventLogs`.

I would like create a scope which will order Users by those with the most occurrences of EventLogs they have.

```
scope :highest_completed_events, .....
```

How can I count the number of EventLogs with a status of 2, and then order the users with the highest occurrence of that type of event.

```
User.joins(:event_logs).where("event_logs.status_id = 2")#... COUNT, then ORDER BY
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a query you can execute to get your users ordered by the number of events they have:

```
@users = User.
  select("users.*, COUNT(event_logs.id) as event_logs_count").
  joins('LEFT JOIN event_logs ON event_logs.user_id = users.id').
  group('users.id').
  order('event_logs_count DESC')
```

You should use a `LEFT JOIN` since you'll want to include users who don't have any events.

If you were to write it as a scope:

```
scope(:highest_completed_events, {
  select: 'users.*, COUNT(event_logs.id) as event_logs_count',
  joins: 'LEFT JOIN event_logs ON event_logs.user_id = users.id',
  group: 'users.id',
  order: 'event_logs_count DESC'
})

@users = User.highest_completed_events
```

In order to filter the events by a particular status, simply use a `where()`.

```
@users = User.
  select("users.*, COUNT(event_logs.id) as event_logs_count").
  joins('LEFT JOIN event_logs ON event_logs.user_id = users.id').
  where('event_logs.status = ?', STATUS_COMPLETE).
  group('users.id').
  order('event_logs_count DESC')
```

---

As an aside, sometimes you'll run into issues with ActiveRecord stripping out your custom `select()` statement when doing something like `@users.count`. What I normally do is nest this kind of thing in a custom `from()` statement.

```
_from = User.
  select("users.*, COUNT(event_logs.id) as event_logs_count").
  joins('LEFT JOIN event_logs ON event_logs.user_id = users.id').
  group('users.id').
  order('event_logs_count DESC').to_sql

@users = User.from("(#{_from}) as users")

@users.count # will work
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
User.all.sort_by{|u| u.event_logs.select{|l| l.status_id = 2}.count}.reverse
```

Or is it 'eventlogs'? Schouldn't your line be `has_many :event_logs` ?

BTW, my solution is not very efficient but DB-agnostic.